# gpg --list-secret-keys won't list keys

Tags: linux, gpg

I've copied `.gnupg` from machine **A** to **B**.
Now on the machine **B** `gpg --list-keys` lists my key but `gpg --list-secret-key` won't unlike on machine **A**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do export and import

```bash
gpg --export-secret-keys <keyid> > my.key
scp my.key remote:~/
# on remote
gpg --import my.key
gpg --list-secret
```